# Replacing a pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the following string:

```
##snapshot

string s = "a,,,b,c,,,,d";

###
```

I am trying to get the following result:

```
"a,null,null,b,c,null,null,null,d";
```

In other words, if there is nothing between two commas, I would like to replace that by "null". I tried the following:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;     

### snapshot

Regex r = new Regex("[\\,\\,]");
Console.WriteLine(r.Replace(s, ",null,"));
```

and I get:

[image]

I don't know much about regular expressions, and this is the best I could come up with, but the result is wrong. What can I try next?

Comment: You are literally printing ",null,". Try replacing with a `""`

Comment: That's my point. I want to literally print null.

Comment: Now it makes sense ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a positive look ahead:

```
string s = "a,,,b,c,,,,d";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(s, ",(?=,)", ",null");
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

Comment: A small follow up. Is it possible to modify the regular expression by adding the logic that: if the comma is at the end of the entire string, then replace that comma by ",null" ?? In other words, if the string was `"a,,b,c,"`, I would want the result to be `"a,null,b,c,null"`.

Comment: This is what I have tried: `Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(s, ",(?=,)", ",null"), ",$", ",null")`

Comment: @Mariam - `(?<=^|,)(?=,|$)` covers both ends, replace with `null`.

Comment: @sln Thanks, but in my case, a comma can never be in the beginning, so I only need to cover the end part!

Comment: @Mariam - Just drop off the `^`, now its `(?<=,)(?=,|$)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex for this operation

```
string s = "a,,,b,c,,,,d";
var str = String.Join(",", s.Split(',')
                            .Select(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? "null" : x));
```

Answer (score 2):

If going to be like a csv but you need fill empty col's you could use a lookbehind and lookahead.

find:  `(?<=^|,)(?=,|$)`
replace `"null"`

Or, if whitespaces involved between commas
find:  `(?<=^|,)\s*(?=,|$)`
replace `"null"`

Answer (score 1):

The [`[]` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#character_classes) in regexes mean "any of these". Remove them, you want to match against `,,` literally.

Or just use [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), no need for regular expressions.

Comment: Removing the `[]` causes an exception

Comment: @Tijesunimi which one? I have no way to test it, but the docs seem to say it should work.

Comment: You answer says he should use `Regex r = new Regex("\\,\\,");`. If i use that it will throw an exception

Answer (score 1):

```
/\,(?=\,)/g
```

use this for positive look ahead and replace it using c# code. with ',null'

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps more intuitive than some answers -- keep checking to see if there is something to replace till done.  (Because you use the "results" of the each match):

```
  string s = "a,,,b,c,,,,d";

  while (Regex.Match(s,"(,,)").Success == true)
    s =  Regex.Replace(s,"(,,)",",null,");
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "a,,,b,c,,,,d";
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",
            s.Split(',')
            .Select(c => string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) ? "null" : c)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed other options, you just just split and rejoin the processed values like so:

```
string s = "a,,,b,c,,,,d";
var cleaned = s.Split(',').Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? "null" : x);
var result = string.Join(",", cleaned);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System;

 public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
        string str = @"a,,,b,c,,,,d";
        Regex pattern = new Regex(@",,");
        string replacement = @",null,";
        Match m = pattern.Match(str);
        while (m.Success)
        {
            str = pattern.Replace(str, replacement);
            m = pattern.Match(str);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as my example.